# Swift: DateFormatter returning nil

Tags: swift, macos, nsdateformatter

I'm having a strange problem with DateFormatter returning nil for a valid data string.

Here is my code:

```
func dateFromString(_ dateString:String,  format: String = "dd/MM/yy") -> Date?
{
    let dueDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dueDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
    dueDateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    let date = dueDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    return date
 }

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    print("Launched")
    let dd = dateFromString("Aug 20", format: "MMM yy")
    print (dd!)
}
```

In the debugger:

[image]

It seems that the variable is set and can be used within the application, but the debugger is not showing it. Is this an Xcode bug or am I going mad?

Everything works fine in the playground and I have used this function many other times in other areas of my code.

I'm using 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: I've never seen someone use `print` in the debugger. I've always used `po`. What does `po dd` produce?

Comment: The debugger output clearly shows "2020-07-31 23:00:00 +0000" from your `print(dd!)`

Comment: For a fixed date format it’s highly recommended to set the `Locale` of the formatter to `en_US_POSIX` especially when dealing with month strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of playing with the debugger, I figured out why this is.

The reason why this happens is because it's `Date`. If you change your method to return an `NSDate`, the debugger shows it correctly.

From what I observed: <s>This behaviour happens for the group of types that `Date`, and others such as `TimeZone` belong to. That is, Swift types in `Foundation` that have an Objective-C counterpart, but isn't a "direct port" like `DateFormatter`/`NSDateFormatter`. I can't really describe it well, but it's basically the types in `Foundation` where their documentation page doesn't let you select an Objective-C version on the top right.</s> This happens for most of the types on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_foundation_types) that are also in `Foundation`. Exceptions are:

- `AffineTransform`
- `Data`
- `DateInterval`
- `Measurement`
- `Notification`

If you use another debugger command, `po`, you'll see that it displays `Date`s correctly. So what's the difference between `print` and `po`?

Running `help print` and `help po` can tell us that:

`print`:

> ```
>     Evaluate an expression on the current thread.  Displays any returned value
>     with LLDB's default formatting.  Expects 'raw' input (see 'help
>     raw-input'.)
>
>     Syntax: print <expr>
>
>     Command Options Usage:
>       print <expr>
>
>
>     'print' is an abbreviation for 'expression --'
> ```

`po`:

> ```
>     Evaluate an expression on the current thread.  Displays any returned value
>     with formatting controlled by the type's author.  Expects 'raw' input (see
>     'help raw-input'.)
>
>     Syntax: po <expr>
>
>     Command Options Usage:
>       po <expr>
>
>     'po' is an abbreviation for 'expression -O  --'
> ```

Notice how for `po` it says "with formatting controlled by the type's author". And if you type `help expression`, you will see what the `-O` option for `expression` does:

> Display using a language-specific description API, if possible.

So it is possible to conclude that `po` is more "specific to Swift" than `print`, hence it is able to print out things like `Date` and `TimeZone`s, because `print` simply doesn't know how to print a Swift `Date`.